# Let the readers to be able to save sets of filters as bookmarks

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I'm currently doing a POC with GDS/BigQuery and AWS QuickSight.
A big drawback with QuickSight is that I can't find a way to let the readers to be able to save sets of filters as bookmarks using a dashboard.
The only workaround is to dupplicate the dashboards but my users may be able to save more than 20 sets of filters so this solution isn't possible.
If someone can help me with this, I didn't find the answer on AWS website neither on the User Guide.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no option to save filters in QuickSight as we can do in PowerBI. A workaround could be to embed QuickSight on a web app and externally filter the data using the APIs. These external filters can then be saved and reused. However, there is significant development efforts involved in this approach.